# How to reduce heat exhaustion of Nvidia GPU (MX110 laptop GPU) on Ubuntu?

Tags: nvidia, intel-graphics, nvidia-optimus, overheating, nouveau

Can anyone help me by guiding how to reduce GPU (Nvidia MX110) temp in Ubuntu? The exhaust of my laptop becomes a hot air blower, even if the graphics rendering is the switched to Intel iGPU and sitting idle. I don't have any heating issue on Windows, but only on Ubuntu. I have tried Xubuntu as well, but no hope of improvement. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Hey Mahfuzur Rahman! Which OS are you using? Ubuntu, Fedora, Debian,..?

Comment: @technastic_tc, I am using ubuntu. I have tried different flavours of ubuntu (xubuntu, kubuntu, mate, gnome), but the problem persists.

Comment: Which versions of Ubuntu did you try? 18.04 or 20.04....?

Comment: @technastic_tc, both 18.04 and 20.04.